# Applications that I can use to create a smooth game for android

Tags: game-engine

Guys were about to begin our capstone project after our the approval of our proposal. We need to create a game that requires logic in order to advance. The smoothness of the game and the transitions is strictly required. But the problem is we dont have a clue on what softwares were going to use. I need suggestions. Any game developer out there?

Comment: What languages are you interested in using?

Comment: Honestly sir were starting from scratch. Last year we learned how to use adobe flash animation but we figured it was laggy and it wasnt that smooth. Any suggestions sir? We still have 2 months to study.

Comment: I've been enjoying messing around with BabylonJS. It is entirely JavaScript. You can see some of the demos at http://www.babylonjs.com/. Also, check out http://race.assassinscreedpirates.com/ for some of its capability. Finally, the forum is super friendly: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/16-babylonjs/

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that who ever approved that project will be sorry for greenlighting it? Oh, that's right ... if you sign on a developer they ought to be at least knowledgeable about the software they are going to use before pitching the project. I can't really say this in a friendly way cause I'm both shocked and apalled about the naivety. Unless this is a student project or something, in that case: sorry for jumping at you. But still, do your research *before* pitching.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I worked with Unity 3D, it's a free software* specially for game developing. It is not limited to one single platform! Check it out:

[Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com)

It covers the languages c# and JavaScript and functions such as PSD (Photoshop format) support for asset files. 2D mode as well as 3D mode, powered by unity engine as far as I understood.

*there is also a paid version, check out this page for more information: 
http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Comment: @JoshuaCollingwood If you want to learn the basics I would also recommend watching a YouTube tutorial series by "brackeys" that guy is extremely nice and a good teacher. He has a tutorial on 2D platformer games in c# and a tutorial for a pong style game in JavaScript.

Comment: I just watched a video by brackeys about an hour ago. And I totally agree with you. Thank you.

Comment: Whoever downvotes answers should leave a comment explaining why.